# Disabling redirect to checkout in Magento 1.9 after adding a product using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

so as the title says I want to stop any redirect after somebody clicked on the add to cart button on the product detail page. The html code looks like this:

```
<button type="button" id="product-addtocart-button" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)">
<span>Add to cart</span></button>
```

I know that I can configure this in the magento backend BUT since this is for an AB-test we can only change this behaviour using css or JS/jQuery.

I tried things I found on other pages like

```
  jQuery('#product-addtocart-button').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //do whatever
  }  );
```

but this doesn't seem to work at all. So my question is if this is even possible and how I could solve this. I am thankful for every bit of help I can get :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
           jQuery('#product-addtocart-button').removeAttr('click');
           jQuery('#product-addtocart-button').click(function(event)
              {
                   event.preventDefault();

              }  );
    });
```

Comment: When I change 'click' to 'onClick' it works but he won't put the item into the cart :(

Comment: Because you change the default functionality

Comment: so basically it would be smarter to create something like 'productAddToCartForm.submit(this)' but without the redirect to the cart page and just change this in the ab-test?!

Comment: So you main goal not to redirect in cart page am I right?

Comment: If user click on add to cart button and you want to user stay no current page then follow this one.

1) Go to admin

 2) System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout

3) After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart

4) Set to No

Comment: have you get any result?

Comment: It works but I can't solve this problem this way because of the ab-test. I definitely need a JS/jQuery solution in any way.